# Swift interacting with WHMCS API

Tags: json, swift, codable

I'm developing a Swift app to interact with my WHMCS API software currently running in a production server. But I'm facing this debug error message when trying to catch and perform the json decoding:

```
keyNotFound(CodingKeys(stringValue: "userid", intValue: nil), Swift.DecodingError.Context(codingPath: [], debugDescription: "No value associated with key CodingKeys(stringValue: \"userid\", intValue: nil) (\"userid\").", underlyingError: nil))
```

The code involved is:

```
import Foundation

class NetworkManager {
    
    @Published var posts = [Results]()
    var privatedata = Credentials()
    
    func fetchData(email: String, password2:String, action: String) {
        switch action {
        case "ValidateLogin":
            if let url = URL(string: "https://XXXXXX.server/includes/api.php?action=\(action)?email=\(email)&password2=\(password2)&username=\(privatedata.api_id)&password=\(privatedata.api_secret)&responsetype=json") {
                let session = URLSession(configuration: .default)
                let task = session.dataTask(with: url) { (data, response, error) in
                    if error == nil {
                        let decoder = JSONDecoder()
                        if let safeData = data {
                            do {
                                let results = try decoder.decode(PostData.self, from: safeData)
                                DispatchQueue.main.async {
//                                    posts.self = results.self
                                }
                                print(results.result)
                            } catch {
                                print(error)
                            }
                        }
                    } else { print("error: \(String(describing: error))")}
                }
                task.resume()
            }
        default:
            print("Error in switch statement")
        }
    }
}
```

Any idea on how to make this run? Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is highly likely that you have defined a `userid` property in your `PostData` model like that:

```
struct PostData: Codable {
    var userid: Int
}
```

and apparently this property do not exists in your response JSON or has `null` value.
Perhaps you should define this property as an optional like this:

```
struct PostData: Codable {
    var userid: Int?
}
```